# How to implement optional arguments in CHICKEN?

Tags: recursion, scheme, tail-recursion, optional-arguments, chicken-scheme

I'm new to CHICKEN and Scheme. In my quest to understanding tail recursion, I wrote:

```
(define (recsum x) (recsum-tail x 0))
(define (recsum-tail x accum)
  (if (= x 0)
      accum
      (recsum-tail (- x 1) (+ x accum))))
```

This does what I expect it to. However, this seems a little repetitive; having an optional argument should make this neater. So I tried:

```
(define (recsum x . y)
  (let ((accum (car y)))
    (if (= x 0)
        accum
        (recsum (- x 1) (+ x accum)))))
```

However, in CHICKEN (and maybe in other scheme implementations), `car` cannot be used against `()`:

```
Error: (car) bad argument type: ()
```

Is there another way to implement optional function arguments, specifically in CHICKEN 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), not for optional procedure arguments. It's a simple way to define a helper procedure with (possibly) extra parameters that you can initialize as required:

```
(define (recsum x)
  (let recsum-tail ((x x) (accum 0))
    (if (= x 0)
        accum
        (recsum-tail (- x 1) (+ x accum)))))
```

Of course, we can also implement it with varargs - but I don't think this looks as elegant:

```
(define (recsum x . y)
  (let ((accum (if (null? y) 0 (car y))))
    (if (= x 0)
        accum
        (recsum (- x 1) (+ x accum)))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(recsum 10)
=> 55
```

Comment: So, in the named let, ((x x) (accum 0)) means "x will be defaulted to x, accum will be defaulted to 0?"

Comment: It's variable bindings, like a normal `let`. Assign `x` to `x` (or any other name you want) and `0` to `accum`. Nice thing is, these assignments occur only once, at the beginning (unlike my second solution, which evaluates the `let` at every iteration).

Comment: Ok, and obviously these bindings are only set initially, not on the recursive call at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Chicken has optional arguments. You can do it like this:

```
(define (sum n #!optional (acc 0))
  (if (= n 0)
      acc
      (sum (- n 1) (+ acc n))))
```

However I will vote against using this as it is non standard Scheme. Chicken say they support  [SRFI-89: Optional positional and named parameters](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html), but it seems it's an earlier version and the egg needs to be redone. Anyway when it is re-applied this should work:

```
;;chicken-install srfi-89 # install the egg
(use srfi-89) ; imports the egg
(define (sum n (acc 0))
  (if (= n 0)
      acc
      (sum (- n 1) (+ acc n))))
```

Also your idea of using rest arguments work. However keep in mind that the procedure then will build a `pair` on the heap for each iteration:

```
(define (sum n . acc-lst)
  (define acc 
    (if (null? acc-lst) 
        0 
        (car acc-lst)))

  (if (= n 0)
      acc
      (sum (- n 1) (+ acc n))))
```

All of these leak internal information. Sometimes it's part of the public contract to have an optional parameter, but in this case it is to avoid writing a few more lines. Usually you don't want someone to pass a second argument and you should keep the internals private. The better way would be to use named `let` and keep the public contract as is.

```
(define (sum n)
  (let loop ((n n) (acc 0))
    (if (= n 0)
        acc
        (loop (- n 1) (+ acc n))))
```

Comment: Interesting that rest arguments build a pair on the heap for each iteration. This suggests rest arguments would never be appropriate for a recursive function. Do you agree?

Comment: @cjp It's remnants from the 60s and the interpreted lisp era. Today Scheme and Common Lisp are stack machines and arguments are pointers on a stack so then when you have rest arguments and just apply it might optimize it, but in the event you start doing `car` on it it has to make a list of the extra arguments on the stack which ends up being on the heap. Rest arguments are great for the flexibility of a contract, but for recursion it's not a good match. Instead of doing rest and perhaps apply it's better to just pass the list as one argument in the recursive procedure.

Comment: The `#!optional` and `#!key` constructs are from DSSSL and they are implemented by collecting rest args into a list and picking that apart. Theoretically, they could be implemented in a more efficient way. It shouldn't even be too hard to implement that, but it simply hasn't been implemented at this moment. Most vararg intrinsics (like `+` and `=`) actually do not first build a list.

Comment: Proper rest args can also be optimised with the [`case-lambda`](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20(chicken%20base)#case-lambda) construct from R7RS / SRFI-16. The same caveat applies here by the way: it could be done, but currently isn't. Come to think of it, I think this might be a nice little project for me to tackle for CHICKEN 5.2...

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a fun little exercise. I made a [ticket](https://bugs.call-cc.org/ticket/1623) for it.